# Need to get the max value in a given string after matching with a column

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Consider this string `'123456789'` and the table consisting of col1 with the values as discribed below:

```
Col1     
123
456
789
```

I need to write a query so the query will have to check for every value in the col1 and output the max matched with the string `'123456789'` in this i need to get output as `789`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
create table t (c varchar2(10));
insert into t values ('123');
insert into t values ('456');
insert into t values ('789');
commit;
```

Query:

```
select c, instr('123456789',c) as pos
  from t
 order by 2 desc 
 fetch first 1 row only;
```

Result:

```
C                 POS
---------- ----------
789                 7
```